# How do I remove a substring from text based on a partial match in Python?

Tags: python, text, data-cleaning

I have a long block of text that contains a subtext that I want to remove based on a partial match (90%).

```
string = "Adam is a boy who lives in Michigan.  
        He loves to eat apples and oranges. 
        He also enjoys playing with his dog and cat. 
        Adam is a happy boy."

substring = "He loves to apple oranges"
```

And I want to return

```
"Adam is a boy who lives in Michigan.  
 He also enjoys playing with his dog and cat. 
 Adam is a happy boy."
```

The words "eat" and "and" don't appear in the substring, but I want to remove the whole sentence "He loves to eat apples and oranges." I'm not really sure how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
'\n'.join(s for s in string.splitlines() if SequenceMatcher(' '.__eq__, s, substring).ratio() < 0.6)
```

This returns:

```
Adam is a boy who lives in Michigan.
He also enjoys playing with his dog and cat.
Adam is a happy boy.
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/twDu1r

Comment: Nice one, I've tried it just now, it works fine. I haven't knew this lib before. Cool thing.

Comment: Thanks! Just a follow up, how would you do it if the text wasn't in different lines and was just a long string?

Comment: @Rachel Glad to be of help. Can you give a sample input and expected output to clarify what you mean by filtering out a partial match of a substring in a long line?

Comment: @Rachel I see. I suppose you can use periods `.` as a marker for the end of a sentence then, in which case use `re.findall(r'\S.*?\.', string)` instead of `string.splitlines()`.

Comment: @blhsing  For instance, if string = "string = "Adam is a boy who lives in Michigan. He loves to eat apples and oranges. He also enjoys playing with his dog and cat. Adam is a happy boy." and substring = "He loves to apple oranges".

And I want to return "Adam is a boy who lives in Michigan. He also enjoys playing with his dog and cat. Adam is a happy boy."

So, basically, not using string.splitlines().

Answer (score 0):

```
string = string.replace(substring,'')
```

This will replace the substring within the string with nothing (`""`)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if the substring exactly matches the sentence that I want to remove? In the example, I want to remove the whole sentence "He loves to eat apples and oranges" but the words "eat" and "and" don't appear in my substring.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Sorry- I thought that was your intention. That's a much deeper problem, then